# Send sysex message with Java

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi, sysex

I'd like to send a Sysex message to a MIDI Port. Unfortunately there is no response at all when I send it. Sending regular MIDI messages (`ShortMessage`) works just fine, but as soon as I replace the `ShortMessage` with the `SysexMessage` things stop working.

```
MidiDevice midiIn = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiDeviceList[NUMBER]);
Receiver rcvr = midiIn.getReceiver
byte[] clearMsg = {(byte) 0xf0, 0x47, 0x7f, 0x15, 0x1e, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xf7 };

SysexMessage sysMsg = new SysexMessage();    
sysMsg.setMessage(clearMsg, clearMsg.length);

rcvr.send(sysMsg, -1);
```

Why doesn't the port receive the message or why isn't it being sent?

Comment: Can you check with a loopback whether the message is sent at all?

Comment: @CL. How would I do that? I tried several MIDI inputs and monitored all IN and OUTs available, but nothing happened.

Comment: Connect the output port to an input port, send both short and SysEx messages, and check (with any sequencer) what you can record from the input.

Comment: @CL. I've tried all ports (Gervill, Real Time Sequencer, OSX's IAC) . ShortMessages work, but no SysEx. My assumption is that there is no message sent, otherwise I would see it in my MIDI Monitoring app.

Answer (score 2):

The reason SysEx messages were not sent is because OSX is has a broken MIDI system. It cannot send SysEx messages. MMJ seems to be a library to workaround this problem.

Comment: Would love to know if this is still true in 2018, as MMJ has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

A more recent solution is https://github.com/DerekCook/CoreMidi4J which is just another dependency you add which will make Midi on OSX work (and do no harm on other platforms).